# cordova 3.4 getpicture success event not firing consistently

Tags: javascript, android, events, cordova, cordova-3

I've been experiencing problems with Cordova 3.4 especially with the sequence of events.

What I'm trying to do is basic.

1) Pick a file from gallery and send to server
2) shoot a pic and send to server

The problem is that after picking a file from the gallery, it doesn't send execute the uploadPhoto routine. And for shooting a pic, you have to shoot a pic 3x before it actually sends it to the uploadPhoto routine.

I basically have cordova@3.4.0-0.1.3 building for Android under lubuntu 13.10 "saucy". Running the apk in Nexus 4 with the PLSX 1.0.9 ROM.

Is there something wrong in my code as to why the success (or even fail) event from the navigator.camera.getPicture isn't triggering consistently?

My index.html is as follows:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
        <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
        <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
        <title>My Sample Program</title>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var pictureSource;   // picture source
            var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value
            var statusDom;

            function uploadFromGallery(){
                //alert("browsing gallery");
                statusDom.innerHTML ="Preparing Gallery";
                log_error("browsing gallery");
                navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, onFail,{ quality: 50, destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
                                            sourceType: pictureSource.PHOTOLIBRARY });
            }

            function capturePhoto() {
              // Take picture using device camera and retrieve image as base64-encoded string
              statusDom.innerHTML ="Preparing Camera";
              log_error("capturing Photo");
              navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, onFail, { quality: 50, destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI });
              //navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { quality: 20, allowEdit: true,destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL });
            }

            function uploadPhoto(imageURI) {
                console.log("sending file:"+imageURI);
                log_error("sending file:"+imageURI);
                var options = new FileUploadOptions();
                options.fileKey="upfile";
                options.fileName=imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/')+".jpg");
                options.mimeType="image/jpeg";
                options.chunkedMode=0;
                //options.chunkedMode = true; //this is important to send both data and files

                //var headers={'Authorization':"Basic " + Base64.encode(username + ":" + password)};
                //options.headers = headers;

                log_error("filename = "+options.fileName)

                var params = {};
                params.usr_nam = "dummy@someserver.com";
                options.params = params;
                var statusDom=document.getElementById('status');
                var ft = new FileTransfer();
                ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
                                                            if (progressEvent.lengthComputable) {
                                                                var perc = Math.floor(progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total * 100);
                                                                statusDom.innerHTML = perc + "% uploaded...";
                                                            } else {
                                                                if(statusDom.innerHTML == "") {
                                                                    statusDom.innerHTML = "Uploading";
                                                                } else {
                                                                    statusDom.innerHTML += ".";
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        };
                ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("https://server_to_somewhere.com/file_capturing_code.php"), win, fail, options);//, 1);
            }

            function win(r) {
                log_error("file sent successfully");
                console.log(dump(r));
                log_error(dump(r));
                return false;
            }

            function fail(error) {
                alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
                console.log(dump(r));
                log_error(dump(r));
            }

            function onFail(message) {
              alert('Failed because: ' + message);
              log_error('Failed because: ' + message);
            }
            function log_error(message)
            {
                var mytextArea=document.getElementById('mini_console');
                mytextArea.value=mytextArea.value+"\n"+message;
            }
            function dump(obj) 
            {
                var out = '';
                for (var i in obj) {
                    out += i + ": " + obj[i] + "\n";
                }
                return out;
            }

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="app">
            <h1>My Sample Program</h1>
            <div id="deviceready" class="blink">
                <p class="event listening">Connecting to Device</p>
                <p class="event received">Device is Ready</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button style="position:relative;top:50%;left:25%;width:200px" type="button" onclick="uploadFromGallery();">Upload from Gallery</button><br>
        <button style="position:relative;top:50%;left:25%;width:200px" type="button" onclick="capturePhoto();">Upload from Camera</button><br>    
        <div>
          <div></div>
          <textarea style="position:relative;top:50%;left:25%;overflow-y:visible;height:60px;width:200px" id="mini_console" >Debug Panel</textarea>
        </div><br/>
        <div id="status"></div>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            app.initialize();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

my index.js is

```
var app = {
    // Application Constructor
    initialize: function() {
        this.bindEvents();
    },
    // Bind Event Listeners
    //
    // Bind any events that are required on startup. Common events are:
    // 'load', 'deviceready', 'offline', and 'online'.
    bindEvents: function() {
        document.addEventListener('deviceready', this.onDeviceReady, false);
    },
    // deviceready Event Handler
    //
    // The scope of 'this' is the event. In order to call the 'receivedEvent'
    // function, we must explicity call 'app.receivedEvent(...);'
    onDeviceReady: function() {
        app.receivedEvent('deviceready');
        pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
        destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;
        statusDom=document.getElementById('status');
    },
    // Update DOM on a Received Event
    receivedEvent: function(id) {
        var parentElement = document.getElementById(id);
        var listeningElement = parentElement.querySelector('.listening');
        var receivedElement = parentElement.querySelector('.received');

        listeningElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:none;');
        receivedElement.setAttribute('style', 'display:block;');

        console.log('Received Event: ' + id);
    }
};
```

Comment: what is your android version currently use?

Comment: What steps did you take to create the project and add the platform and plugins?

Comment: I copied your code and tried it but I get a lot of console warnings and errors. Have you tried working through all of those?

Comment: @Dato'MohammadNurdin - my Android version is (phone) 4.4.2 while my AndroidManifest.xml targets <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

Comment: @MBillau - I've compiled this in cordova ('cordova build') and no errors were seen. I of course installed lots of cordova plugins ('cordova plugin'). Here are the plugins I used for this project
[ 'org.apache.cordova.camera',
  'org.apache.cordova.console',
  'org.apache.cordova.device',
  'org.apache.cordova.file',
  'org.apache.cordova.file-transfer',
  'org.apache.cordova.inappbrowser',
  'org.apache.cordova.network-information'

Comment: @MBillau - normal steps basically create the project (cordova create) then add the platform (cordova platform add android) then add the plugins for the permissions (cordova plugin) and then started coding.

Comment: Do you see a bunch of errors in logcat when you navigate to the page? I see lots of things like`[INFO:CONSOLE(26)] "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of undefined", source: file:///android_asset/www/index.html (26)`. You have to fix these errors before expecting it will work. I think the quickest way would be to get rid of your `index.js` and wrap the relevant js code in your index.html with `deviceReady()`.

Comment: nope, no errors really. I have the whole thing running in Android and am using chrome//:inspect to show if there are errors in the running program.. aside from two minor warnings, there are no errors per say in the console.